# reg expression to retrieve the values from data

Tags: regex, postgresql

What is the regular expression to evaluate the values from the below string in the `postgres` environment:

```
"((x.y.z == "test") OR (a.b.c intersects "test1") OR  OR (pub.custom.channel intersects "test2,test3"))"
```

Need output as : `test,test1,test2,test3`

Comment: In what language/environment/tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
regexp_replace(subject, '(?:\A[^"]*)?"([^"]+)"[^"]+(?:"([^"]+)"[^"]*\Z)?', '\1,\2', 'g')
```

Comment: thanks,it is giving what i expected.